Is there a way to switch the current task to a higher priority task with asyncio?
The current project I am working on involves a rate-limited API where you cannot make more than 100 requests in a minute window. I am trying to build some logic that will prevent my code from going beyond this limit using asyncio sleep to wait until there is an available slot to make a request. After some research I believe I've pretty much just reinvented something similar to the token bucket algorithm.
What I believe the problem to be is that when I send a large collection of async tasks to be computed, the following happens:

As soon as space is freed up, some of the running tasks exit the loop and try to run their computation
This computation involves the API request which must also be awaited
This request is added onto the call stack
However, the request is never sent because asyncio is stuck on the other tasks which are in a sleep loop waiting for more space to be allocated
This never happens because the code still thinks that the requests haven't completed yet
The code halts

Here is a simplified version of the code that demonstrates the issue I currently have:
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from datetime import datetime


timeout_start = datetime.now()
active_calls = 0
completed_calls = 0

TIME_WINDOW = 3
MAX_CALLS = 5


async def task(i):
    global timeout_start, active_calls, completed_calls

    while active_calls + completed_calls >= MAX_CALLS:
        wait = TIME_WINDOW - (datetime.now() - timeout_start).seconds
        if wait > 0:
            await asyncio.sleep(wait)
        else:
            completed_calls = 0

    active_calls += 1
    print(f'Task {i} start - ({active_calls}-{completed_calls})')

    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get('https://www.google.com/') as response:
            active_calls -= 1
            completed_calls += 1

            if timeout_start is None:
                timeout_start = datetime.now()

            print(f'Task {i} complete - ({active_calls}-{completed_calls})')


async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(*[task(i) for i in range(20)])

asyncio.run(main())

To summarise the code, it tries to make 20 requests to google.com but with a maximum of 5 requests every 3 seconds.
This outputs the following:
Task 0 start - (1-0)
Task 1 start - (2-0)
Task 2 start - (3-0)
Task 3 start - (4-0)
Task 4 start - (5-0)
Task 2 complete - (4-1)
Task 1 complete - (3-2)
Task 4 complete - (2-3)
Task 3 complete - (1-4)
Task 0 complete - (0-5)
Task 5 start - (1-0)
Task 6 start - (2-0)
Task 7 start - (3-0)
Task 8 start - (4-0)
Task 9 start - (5-0)

However then it halts forever. I believe this is because when the second batch of tasks hit the start print, they cannot go any further as their requests have to wait for the other coroutines to complete.
Actual Question
Is there a way to fix this code to prevent it from halting? My initial idea is that somehow I label the tasks which hit the start print as prioritised so they are run first, but I'm not sure how or if asyncio allows that.

Also its important to note that in the real program, each of these tasks will return some data. So a solution would need to preserve the property that each function call will receive the correct data for its arguments. Otherwise this could be simply solved by just sending waiting calls onto a stack or queue.

This program enters a busy while loop at else: completed_calls = 0. I would suggest to implement the real tocken bucket, e.g. with a semaphor)
